# How to specify path of output database in IDA Pro?

Tags: ida, command-line

I'm trying to generate IDB files from the command-line using the `-o` flag of IDA, something like this:
`ida.exe -B input.dll -oC:\Results\input.idb`. However, it seems that the value of the `-o` arguments are completely ignored.

I've tried this with `ida.exe`, `ida64.exe`, `idat.exe`, and `idat64.exe`. I've tried adding `-c` and also tried removing `-B` flags. None of these work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any switches after the input filename are ignored. Just move the filename to the end.